# MySQL complex count on cross join

Tags: mysql, count, cross-join

Thank you for reading, I've tried this for four hours now with some good progress but I just can't get my head around it.

I've simplified the application to just the parameters I'm struggling with.

I have a database of customers that have used services, one for each year and two lookup tables to allow for coding of the results.

```
Table - Gender
gender_code | gender_name
          1 | Male
          2 | Female
          3 | Other

Table - Service
service_code | service_name
           1 | WiFi
           2 | Network
           3 | Telephone

Table - Customers13
transactionid | customerid | service_code | gender_code
            1 |          4 |            3 |           1
            2 |          7 |            1 |           2
            3 |          9 |            1 |           1

Table - Customers14
transactionid | customerid | service_code | gender_code
            1 |         13 |            2 |           2
            2 |          4 |            2 |           1
            3 |         17 |            2 |           2
```

What I want to get is a table returned which has all possible permutations of service and gender and a count of each for each year. I started off trying to get the count right and used the following MySQL query:

```
select t.service_name, t.gender_name, count13, count14
from (select service_name, gender_name, count(Customers13.gender_code) as count13
from Customers13  
inner join Gender on Customers13.gender_code = Gender.gender_code  
inner join Service on Customers13.service_code = Service.service_code 
group by service_name, gender_name) t
inner join (select service_name, gender_name, count(Customers14.gender_code) as count14
from Customers14  
inner join Gender on Customers14.gender_code = Gender.gender_code  
inner join Service on Customers14.service_code = Service.service_code 
group by service_name, gender_name) m on m.service_name=t.service_name and 
m.gender_name=t.gender_name
```

This gets me close returning the table I want but only where there is a match in both tables. What I want is to get a line even when there is a match in no tables, for example:

```
service_name | gender_name | count13 | count14
WiFi         | Male        |       1 |       0
WiFi         | Female      |       1 |       0
WiFi         | Other       |       0 |       0
Network      | Male        |       0 |       1
Network      | Female      |       0 |       2
Network      | Other       |       0 |       0
Telephone    | Male        |       1 |       0
Telephone    | Female      |       0 |       0
Telephone    | Other       |       0 |       0
```

My last attempt was to use a cross join to get the first two columns correct but I've no idea how to make the jump to populating the count fields from there:

select service_name, gender_name from Service cross join Gender

Comment: In order to simply it a bit, have you considered using a set, instead of what I assume is a char or varchar? Something like set('WiFi','Network','Telephone')

Comment: The data is not mine, it is in .csv format, however the schema is absolutely mine so I could certainly set up the fields in any way I want.  Set is not something I have used before but if it simplifies the problem then it is something I'm very amenable to.

Comment: You have a table for each year? But why? That seems like such a poor and unnecessary idea.

Comment: Also " Gender_gender_code " Is that right?

Comment: In many industries annual reporting is necessary, it doesn't mean that the data is held in a database table for each year, just that sometimes an output needs to be manipulated that is broken down into annual files

Comment: Thanks have corrected Gender.gender_code.  The fault comes from me simplifying the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind all genders to all services with a cross join, then left join the union subquery:

```
SELECT
    s.service_name, g.gender_name, COUNT(c.cnt13), COUNT(c.cnt14)
FROM
    service s
CROSS JOIN
    gender g
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT gender_code, service_code, 1 AS cnt13, NULL AS cnt14
        FROM Customers13
        UNION ALL
        SELECT gender_code, service_code, NULL, 1
        FROM Customers14
    ) AS c
    USING (gender_code, service_code)
GROUP BY s.service_name, g.gender_name
```

Comment: you beautiful, beautiful person! that works perfectly. I was so close I just couldn't get them to join properly, it looks like the USING made all the difference.

Comment: USING is just another way of writing join conditions, the left join in combination with the cross joinj did the trick ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

```
select
service_name, gender_name, sum(cnt13), sum(cnt14)
from
(
   select service_name, gender_name, count(c.GENDER_CODE) as cnt13, 0 as cnt14
   from SERVICE s,gender g,customers13 c
   where c.GENDER_CODE=g.GENDER_CODE
   and c.SERVICE_CODE=s.SERVICE_CODE
   group by service_name, gender_name
   union all
   select service_name, gender_name, 0 as cnt13, count(c.GENDER_CODE) as cnt14
   from SERVICE s,gender g,customers14 c
   where c.GENDER_CODE=g.GENDER_CODE
   and c.SERVICE_CODE=s.SERVICE_CODE
   group by service_name, gender_name
)
group by service_name, gender_name
```

Comment: I get the error: 'Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias.' Thank you for your help to this point.

Comment: OK so I've altered the c alias to a d and it works to a point.  It doesn't give me a count where there are no matching values and it essentially puts one table on top of the other which is unfortunate.  Thank you for your help though, it is appreciated.